# import a tkinter widget to another file

Tags: tkinter

There are two files; test2.py and test3.py.

in test2.py
G1 is a button, and when it is pushed, it will run the test3.py file.
the file contains a class for a text box.

```
`root.geometry("1100x700+100+300")
frame = Frame(root)
G1 = Button(root, text="G1", fg="blue", \
            width=20, command = lambda: g1(CheckVarG1)).place(x=320, y=25)
def g1(CheckVarG1):
        os.system('python3 test3.py')
class MUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.text = Text(master,font=('courier', 15, 'normal'),width=87, height=6)`
```

in test3.py

```
`import MUI from test2
k = MUI(master)
k.text.insert('end', 'message')`
```

When I run the test2.py file, it regenerates the first menu, and I am getting the error;
     k = MUI(master)
NameError: name 'master' is not defined

Comment: What's the class `MyFirstGUI`?Could you show a minimal example of your code?

Comment: My mistake - Class name is MUI. In test3.py, should be k=MUI(master)